# Passport control formalities for former US citizen at US POE

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, us-visa-waiver-program

My wife and I are former US citizens and need to travel to the US. My wife is terrified of the horror stories about [CBP](https://www.cbp.gov/) and Passport Control. We are both citizens of a [VWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Waiver_Program) country, employed, and have family in the US. Both passports are biometric, brand-new, and without stamps. We both have ESTA approvals.

Has any other **former** US citizen been sent to secondary screening and delayed at US airports?

Comment: Did you relinquish US citizenship in the manner that the US government recognizes?

Comment: You should also be sure you have no unsatisfied tax obligations to the US Treasury.

Comment: @NateEldredge if they hadn't, would they have been able to get ESTA approval?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_Amendment_(immigration)

Comment: @Nate and Johns. Thank you for your answer. All obligations have been fulfilled and accepted by the US government.

Comment: Err.. Nate did not answer, rather, he asked a question. And a rather important one. Please do yourself the favor of answering it.

Comment: @Michael. You are correct, thanks for the clarification. I assumed that his question would have been answered by my response confirming that the obligations for relinquishment  (which includes tax compliance) were recognized by the government. Also, Phoog's comment was correct.